# Android: draw Bitmap to TextView not working

Tags: android, bitmap

Another day, another error, ah the life of a new programmer. I'm trying to draw a `bitmap` into a `TextView` or `ImageView` and its not working. I have been looking at this code for a couple hours, trying to figure out why it's not working. Below is the code. I'm not receiving any errors, and the program runs, it simply does not display the bitmap

**CustomView.java**

```
public class CustomView extends ImageView {

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);     
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);      
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);        
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}   

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap line = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.line);
    canvas.drawBitmap(line, 0, 0, null);
            super.onDraw(canvas);       
}
}

@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   // Hail Mary. If this works then look up how to really use 'onMeasure()'.
   setMeasuredDimension(200, 50);
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    refreshView();
}

private void refreshView() {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, model.getLocationsArray());

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd");

    TextView goalText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.goal_Id);
    TextView dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_Id);
    TextView countText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
    TextView daysText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days);
    TextView totalText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    TextView aveText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ave);       

    GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
    goalText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    goalText.setText("Today's Goal: Don't Smoke at ");
    dateText.setText(sdf.format(now.getTime()));
    //get today's count from data in the SQLite table - count entries with today's date
    countText.setText("" + mySmokinDatabase.getTodaysCount());
    // Table data
    daysText.setText("" + String.format("%10d", model.getDays()));
    totalText.setText("" + mySmokinDatabase.getTotal());

    if (model.getDays() > 0)
        aveText.setText("" + mySmokinDatabase.getTotal()/model.getDays());

}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<ImageView class="com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView"
    android:id="@+id/line_Id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/line"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

**Logcat**

```
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smokin4ThomasSullivan/com.example.smokin4
ThomasSullivan.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21:  
Error inflating class com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class 
com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at   
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
com.example.smokin4ThomasSullivan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     ... 11 more
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474): Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at  
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at   
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at  
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
03-22 20:17:47.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     ... 21 more`
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The logcat is clear. What's at line 73?

Comment: @Simon `Line 73: spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`
Which is crazy because that code is in the refresh view method posted above and it hasnt been touched, and its also working if I don't use this imageview. I get the error as soon as I set perform this 
`line: setContentView(new CustomView(this));`

Comment: Not crazy at all.  onCreate() is called as soon as your activity is loaded which in turn, calls refresh() so yes, the code "is touched".  Since adapter is new, spinner must be null (you could of course check in the debugger). Therefore, findviewById() is not finding the spinner in the currently inflated layout.  By the way, your question  title is non-sensical and does not describe the problem you are having.  You cannot "draw" a bitmap to a TextView.

Comment: @Simon If I update the code to say `setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)` the program boots up in my avd but just doesnt display the bitmap. It says nothing about the spinner being null. I guess I'm just not understanding how that effects my program

Comment: @Simon Nevermind, I get it. In the main_activity layout there is all the xml to hold all my textviews, spinners etc. So when I change it to CustomView(this) it no longer holds any of the values so the first thing it comes across which is the spinner, is then null, because it isnt declared in the layout. However this still does not solve why this bitmap isnt displaying

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do, but can't you just add CustomView to main_layout.xml?

Comment: I just want to display a couple pictures in between the `TextViews` on the Main Activity. I don't understand the "add CustomView to main_layout.xml" Because CustomView.java is a class and main_layout.xml is an xml file. How do I add java files to xml files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410616/how-to-add-custom-view-to-the-layout

Comment: @Simon I understand that, I misunderstood what you said then. Aren't I already doing that in my post above? Look at main_activity.xml. In my set up I say 
`<ImageView class="com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView"
    android:id="@+id/line_Id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/line"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26753/discussion-between-irishwhiskey-and-simon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to understand the purpose of doing things this way.  Wouldn't it be simpler to create a RelativeLayout with a TextView on top of an ImageView?  Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or even better, place the TextView in a LinearLayout, and set the image to the LinearLayout's background?

Edit, reply to comment:

It's not about being efficient, it's about trying to put a square peg in a round hole.  It basically seems as if you're setting a single object - the custom ImageView - as the entire layout, then attempting to add additional elements to the single object (the TextView).  Attempting to do is exactly what the Layout objects are for: containing a collection of other objects.  In this case, ImageViews and TextViews.

Of course, I might have missed the purpose here.  If it's an exercise in unusual ways of doing things, then I understand.  However, if you're just attempting to get things on the screen, it seems like a very complicated way of doing that.  Typically, the command `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` sets an XML file with the root object being some version of a Layout object (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.)  Within that layout would be the objects you want to manipulate.  Perhaps we don't have the entirety of your MainActivity.xml?

Comment: I really don't think this helps me. My problem is not how to redesign my program to be more efficient. It's why doesn't the bitmap appear in my view on my Main Activity

Comment: Is CustomView an ImageView or a TextView? CustomView.java extends TextView while MainActivity.xml uses ImageView.

Answer (score 3):

Your XML code contains:

```
<ImageView class="com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView" />
```

This is going to create an `ImageView`, not an instance of `CustomView`. This means that your custom `onDraw()` method will never be executed. The syntax you are looking for is:

```
<com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView />
```

The `class` attribute works only with the `<view />` tag (and it required only when you want to reference an inner class because they contain $ in their name.)

Comment: Well I tried your solution, which may very well be correct. However now I get a nice long logcat error and my program crashes. The logcat is posted at the bottom of my original question. It basically says it can't find my CustomView class, or that it doesn't exist

Comment: You didn't paste enough of the stack trace. The reason of the crash should be further down. It could be that your class is in the wrong package, not static, etc.

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: `Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView` -- you apparently do not have a `com.example.smokin4thomassullivan.CustomView` in your project. That is probably because elsewhere, you are using `com.example.smokin4ThomasSullivan` (note capital letters). Java package names, by convention, are lowercase. Regardless, you need to stick to something and use it consistently everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to test your extend of ImageView:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    System.out.println("onDraw");
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(0xFFFF8844);
    paint.setTextSize(12.0F);
    canvas.drawText("Hello David!", 100, 100, paint);
}
```

Get rid of `onMeasure()`.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer David Manpearl. However this does not solve the problem. I changed the `onDraw` and it still does not display in my Activity. I've edited the original post to show the changes in my MainActivity and the onDraw

Comment: Ooops, I did extend TextView in my CustomView.java. I really thought you had the answer there, but nope. It still doesn't display the bitmap on my activity. I updated the code at the top to show the changes

Comment: Try the temporary 'onDraw()' suggestion just edited into my answer.

Comment: that doesn't display either, what does this mean?