# Plot graph of Red vs Time: OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-graphview

I am using OpenCV in my android application which detects the RGB value of an object in front of the camera. I can successfully detect the RGB value (not perfect because my phone camera keeps adjusting the brightness), and i want to plot a graph of the Red/Blue/Green value against time. I would also like to limit the video to 1 minute. I am using the GraphView library to plot the graph. The problem is the graph view takes 2 parameters, the x (time) and y (my R/G/B value) and since I am could not find a solution to set the timer, I cant plot the graph.
Can anyone help me understand how to set the timer so that the video is recorded to a certain period of time?

```
public class VideoRecordingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{

//java camera view
JavaCameraView javaCameraView;

Mat mRgba, mHsv;

GraphView graph;

//callback loader
BaseLoaderCallback mCallBackLoader = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {


        switch (status){
            case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:
                javaCameraView.enableView();
                break;
            default:
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
        }
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_recording);

    //connect the camera
    javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);

    //set visibility
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(320, 240);

    javaCameraView.enableFpsMeter();
    javaCameraView.clearFocus();

    //set callback function
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    /*Graph*/
    graph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graphView);


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(javaCameraView!=null){
        javaCameraView.disableView();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (javaCameraView!=null){
        javaCameraView.disableView();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Log.d("openCV", "Connected");

        //display when the activity resumed,, callback loader
        mCallBackLoader.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);


    }else{
        Log.d("openCV", "Not connected");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_3_0, this, mCallBackLoader);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    //4 channel
    mRgba = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mHsv = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    //release
    mRgba.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    //get each frame from camera
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();


    /**********HSV conversion**************/
    //convert mat rgb to mat hsv
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    //find scalar sum of hsv
    Scalar mColorHsv = Core.sumElems(mHsv);

    int pointCount = 320*240;


    //convert each pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < mColorHsv.val.length; i++) {
        mColorHsv.val[i] /= pointCount;
    }

    //convert hsv scalar to rgb scalar
    Scalar mColorRgb = convertScalarHsv2Rgba(mColorHsv);

    //print scalar value
    Log.d("intensity", "R:"+ String.valueOf(mColorRgb.val[0])+" G:"+String.valueOf(mColorRgb.val[1])+" B:"+String.valueOf(mColorRgb.val[2]));

    int R = (int) mColorRgb.val[0];
    int G = (int) mColorRgb.val[1];
    int B = (int) mColorRgb.val[2];

    Log.d("intensity", "Y:"+ String.valueOf(Y)+" U:"+String.valueOf(U)+" V:"+String.valueOf(V));


    /*>>>>>>>>GRAPH<<<<<<<<<<*/

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
            new DataPoint(0, R),
            new DataPoint(1, R),
            new DataPoint(2, R),
            new DataPoint(3, R)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);




    return mRgba;

}



//convert Mat hsv to scalar
private Scalar convertScalarHsv2Rgba(Scalar hsvColor) {
    Mat pointMatRgba = new Mat();
    Mat pointMatHsv = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, hsvColor);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(pointMatHsv, pointMatRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB);

    return new Scalar(pointMatRgba.get(0, 0));
 }
}
```

the video is at around 15-20 fps. I want to plot the R/G/B value of each frame against time. 
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Start by using the frame number instead of time. If you know the frame rate (and can assume it's constant within one recording), you can calculate the timespan between two frames -- e.g. 10 FPS -> 0.1s between consecutive frames.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I tried to do that however, there is a problem. To see fps of my app I have used the enableFpsMeter() (shows around ~25) method of the OpenCV JavaCameraView class. But i dont know how to store the fps into a variable. So working with the fps is another bit issue. can you suggest me some solutions to store the fps into a variable.

Comment: Check this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271832/set-frame-rate-in-javacameraview) as well as the [sample code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-3-cameracontrol) it refers to.

Comment: i have used your suggestions and everything is fine until when i call the `setPreviewFps()` method. The program crashes. There is no error report in the debugger.. it just crash.

Comment: Hi @DanMašek hope i can reach you.. I have been trying to implement this in my app. I want to set a fixed fps which i believe can be achieved with params.setPreviewRangeFps(x, x). I have created the class extending the JavaCameraView class and can access the all methods accordingly. EX: customizableCameraView.enableFpsMeter() etc. However, when i try to access the customizableCameraView.setPreviewFps(x,x) my app crash without any error report. I have tried to create other methods like the one for resolution in the example. But it still crash when ever i try to access. What am i missing?