# How to set a path for a class that extends View in xml? Android-Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I found the following class https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/accessory/demokit/+/4de77996b19a3851675080072f029b0c7d0865ff/app/src/com/google/android/DemoKit/ColorWheel.java, but I don't really know how to display it. I am quite new to android and I haven't used something like this until now. Could you tell me how to make that class display in an activity ?

When I do this

```
<com.google.android.packageName.ColorWheel> android:id="@+id/view" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" </com.google.android.packageName.ColorWheel>
```

Comment: [From the comments](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorPickerDialog.html)

Comment: That link takes me to "about sample data".Where should I go from there ? Could you give me some examples ? Thank you:D

Comment: The link is bad, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410616/how-to-add-custom-view-to-the-layout

Comment: I did that and I get I get a big error if I do only that xD .  "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.packageName.ColorWheel on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/packageName-58.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/packageName-58, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]" .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the fully qualified path of the custom view in your layout xml.

So this:

```
<com.google.android.DemoKit.ColorWheel></com.google.android.DemoKit.ColorWheel>
```

instead of just this:

```
<ColorWheel></ColorWheel>
```

Note that you'll need to modify the package to match where the class exists in your project, i.e. `com.google.android.DemoKit` will need to be changed to whatever `package` this `View` subclass exists in.

Comment: <com.google.android.packageName.ColorWheel>
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    </com.google.android.packageName.ColorWheel>