# How can I solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I found this post [Android ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523167/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path). But I don't know how to do that in android studio. I get the same error as he did : `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.packageName.ClassName" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/packageName-58.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/packageName-58, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]].`

Comment: You'll need to post the code of the Activity for us to help, but the class "com.google.packageName.ClassName" looks more like placeholder text that has been left in the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618444/how-to-set-a-path-for-a-class-that-extends-view-in-xml-android-studio/28618997#28618997

Comment: Please update the title of the question to the actual question. It would save time of many people. Thanks.

Comment: I'm really sorry for that. I changed it.